# System settings / Sound test fails to produce sound ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, vlc, hdmi

I have been trying to get a TV card and mplayer to work on ubuntu 16.04. I get the picture but no sound. 
I opened System Settings / Sound and clicked on "Sound Test" then clicked on  "Front Left" then on "Front Right" but get no sound at all.
When I use VLC to play a video or music the sound is good.

My monitor is connected via an HDMI cable but the HDMI sound is muted.The speakers are plugged into the on-board sound device.

How do I get the "Sound" app to function properly ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I used:

sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center

to remove the Unity Control Centre and then used:

sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

to reinstall it again.

After this process the "Sound Test" works perfectly.

Comment: That did the trick for me! In my case unity-control-center was not installed after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After installing it, I could select and test the different outputs again in the system settings.